# Gatsby setHeadComponents setting async tag

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I am rendering a 3rd party script tag using Gatsby's `onRenderBody` and `setHeadComponents` API in gatsby-ssr.js.

```
export const onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }) => {
  setHeadComponents([
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      async
      key="1"
      src="//www.myscripturl.com/analytics.js"
    />,
  ])
}
```

However, the HTML that is output sets the `async` tag as `async=""`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//www.myscripturl.com/analytics.js"></script>
```

It's not clear to me if this is allowing async loading of the script or not. Typically, I'd expect the script to output as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="//www.myscripturl.com/analytics.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> For classic scripts, if the `async` attribute is present, then the
> classic script will be fetched in parallel to parsing and evaluated as
> soon as it is available.
>
> For module scripts, if the `async` attribute is present then the scripts
> and all their dependencies will be executed in the `defer` queue,
> therefore they will get fetched in parallel to parsing and evaluated
> as soon as they are available.

So, `async=""`, `async=true`, or `async=false` will be parsed exactly in the same way because the attribute, whenever it's present, will be evaluated as `async` either way.

> It's not clear to me if this is allowing async loading of the script
> or not. Typically,

Yes, it will be loaded asynchronously.

You can use a more semantic if you want way using a `true` value but will have no effect on the final result because the `async` attribute if it's present, will load the script asynchronously, no matter the value of the attribute.

```
export const onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }) => {
  setHeadComponents([
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      async=true
      key="1"
      src="//www.myscripturl.com/analytics.js"
    />,
  ])
}
```